# Why is port scanning with python sockets so much slower on Windows than it is on linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, sockets, security

I've tried looking around online through different python docs, forums, and other people's questions but I haven't found anyone with this same question.

What my scripts typically look like is I'll create a socket connection that tries connecting to ports 1-9999 and will only tell me when a port is open. When I run this on windows it takes 1 second to scan a port before moving on to the next one (60 ports/m. ~16.5m for 1000 ports). When I run the same scripts on linux, it'll cycle through all 9999 ports very quickly, while still returning the same desired results.

I was hoping to be able to build cross-compatible tools, but it appears linux 
 is just the better operating system when it comes to my networking needs? I have both at my disposal so I don't mind using one over the other. I'd just like to know if there's anything that could be done to make port scanning almost as equally fast on both operating systems, otherwise I won't spend as much time building on/for windows.

The difference in speed is the same regardless of which network I'm on.

My questions are:
•Why is the performance so different on windows compared to linux when given the same functions?
•Is there anything that can be done to make port scanning with sockets faster like it is on linux?

--edit--

here's the piece I use to check ports

```
def whole_scan(Host_):
    service = ''
    host = Host_
    max_port = 9999
    min_port = 1
    def scan_host(host, port, r_code = 1):
        try:
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            code = s.connect_ex((host, port))
            if code == 0:
                r_code = code
                s.close()
        except Exception, e:
            pass
        return r_code
        hostip = gethostbyname(host)
    for port in range(min_port, max_port):
        try:
            response = scan_host(host,port)
            if response == 0:
                try:
                    service = getservbyport(port)
                except Exception, e:
                    service = 'n/a'
            print(" |--port: %d\t%s" % (port,service.upper()))
        except Exception, e:
            pass
```

I've also verified my firewall is disabled and adding the value to my registry to disable the limit on connections had no change on performance. I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Since unix was built for networking and networking was built for unix, any brand of unix, including linux-based systems arguably has an edge when choosing a networking platform. That being said, it's likely something else is at work here. Do you have some firewall enabled on your windows box? It could block the RST,ACK packets that notify of a (unfiltered) closed port.

Comment: @spectras the AV on my laptop is disabled and netsh advfirewall show allprofiles shows all firewalls are off. I'd like to think there's got to be something but I'm having a hard time finding it

Comment: Can you provide a simplified, self-contained benchmark with numbers for both OS? There are many ways of doing port scanning (blocking vs nonblocking, parallel vs sequential, connect vs syn), so it would be good to have a specific example plus actual numbers.

Comment: @thatotherguy I don't have anything that keeps track of time, but I've provided the bit of code that cycles through all the ports in my post

Answer (score 0):

Windows limits the concurrent number of half-open connections and that may be at play here if you are opening that many connection requests at a time. For example, on Windows 7 try setting this key value to 0 (to disable it)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\EnableConnectionRateLimiting

Comment: I looked into that and though the entry doesn't exist on win X, I did see an article that said the same thing could be created if not there already on 8, so I tried it and unfortunately there was no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is causing the performance problem, however, there is a bug in your `scan_host()` function.

This function attempts to return `r_code`, however, `r_code` is only set if `connect_ex()` returns `0`. Should `connect_ex()` return a non-zero value, or an exception were to occur in the same block of code, `r_code` would not be set, and the `return` statement would raise a `NameError` exception. This exception will propagate to the calling code, which catches it then and ignores it and all other exceptions.

It's not a good idea to ignore exceptions; perhaps you might learn something relevant to the problem, perhaps not, but I suggest that you log the exceptions that are occurring.

Also, it would be useful if you added some debug print statements into your code. This will help you locate the part of your code where the majority of time is spent.

There is also the line:

```
hostip = gethostbyname(host)
```

which never seems to be executed - I can't tell because perhaps the indentation in your post is not quite right.

Another thing to consider is DNS. Possibly the DNS server used by Windows is slower, or there is some issue there. You could eliminate that by using the IP address instead of host name:

```
response = scan_host(gethostbyname(host), port)
```

Comment: I'm positive this isn't the issue. I've done something similar but older with a tcp client that tried connecting to a range of ports using socket.connect(host,port) and had the same performance issue with it being fast on linux but slow on windows. I appreciate you pointing that out though! I'll change that in my code when I get home

Comment: By checking the exceptions you might well get a clue. Similarly, adding debug statements with time stamps might also help.  I've also updated my answer with a few other suggestions.

Comment: Also, the hostip doesn't serve a purpose in this section of the code, but the DNS sounds interesting and isn't something I had considered. I had assumed windows and linux were using the same DNS server since I never specified which one I'd like for them to use.

Comment: `connect_ex()` will be resolving the host name, possibly requiring a DNS lookup each time (unless there is caching). Any delays there will add up. Also, less likely, time how long `getservbyport()` is taking... I don't know how it's implemented in Windows, it should just be a database/file lookup, but possibly it's more complicated.